# web.xml - <http-method> absent

Tags: xml, security, jsp, http-method, deployment-descriptor

I'm wondering if I've found a mistake in a practice exam question:

> A user has configured security setting in the deployment descriptor, web.xml, in the following way:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ResourceName</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/test.jsp</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

> Which HTTP methods can the user call against `test.jsp`?

The correct answer is listed as **none**, but I'm thinking that all methods should be valid, as the `<http-method>` element is absent. Which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

> **The http-method Element**
>
> The  element declares which HTTP methods (usually, GET or
>   POST) are subject to the security constraint. If  element
>   is omitted, the the security constraint is applied to all HTTP methods
>   by default.

[web.xml Deployment Descriptor Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/webapp/web_xml.html#wp1017885)

Comment: Right, so wouldn't all HTTP methods be valid in the above example?

Comment: The security constraint should be applied to all methods, no one could access to test.jsp with any HTTP method. Try doing a simple webapp with a single jsp and test it.

Comment: Thanks. I guess what I'm missing is what in the deployment descriptor stops the HTTP methods from accessing? I understand why the code applies to all methods, just not what **stops** them from accessing (rather than allows access by all).

Comment: Take a look at this article http://java.dzone.com/articles/understanding-web-security

Comment: Thanks for the article - but it still appears to me that all methods should be open, as no `<auth-constraint>` element is included (meaning no restriction is placed on a method?):
_Use Case: We would like to exclude a set of web resources from any access. This can arise when a certain portion of the web application needs to undergo some form of maintenance or is not applicable for a particular physical deployment of a generic web application. We will achieve this with authorization constraints that specify no roles._

Comment: If you do not define an auth-constraint and not define http methods the resource will be allowed for all with all methods, if you define an auth-constraint and not define http methods the constraint will be effective for all http methods, if you define some methods the constraint will be effective for that defined methods.

Comment: Right - so the above example should allow all for all methods, since no `auth-constraint` is defined, correct? Thanks again.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it appears from specs that @JeffLevine was indeed correct. The absence of `http-method` elements indicates the security constraint applies to all methods. The absence of an `auth-constraint` element indicates no access restriction. Meaning all HTTP methods are available. A simple test should give conclusive evidence of the exam answer being faulty. Did you ever manage to get this rectified?